# Google Apps Script - get google sheets cell as an argument for modify it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to do plus(B3) as B3 cell is an argument, i didnt understand how to do it so currently my code is:

```
function plusB3() {
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B3");
cell.setValue(cell.getValue()+1);
}
```

how can i get the cell lets say "B3" ->> plus(b3) as an argument instead of each time modify the function
i want to do something like:

```
function plus(arg) {
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(arg);
cell.setValue(cell.getValue()+1);
}
```

but it doesnt seem to work, please help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the argument as string:

```
=plus("B3")
```

or parse it inside the custom function using `getFormula()` and regex:

```
=plus(B3)
```

```
function plus(cell) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const cellString = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula().match(/=plus\((.*)\)/i)[1];
  const yesCount = ss.getRange(cellString);
  const yesAdd = yesCount.getValue();
  yesCount.setValue(yesAdd+1);
}
```